# How do you say "using X as a Y"?

Tags: grammar, translation

In Issunboushi, there is a line that goes like this.
"Issunboushi wa hari wo katana ni shite koshi ni sashi"
I found a translation that says "He made use of a needle as a sword", but I have no idea why. True, hari=needle, katana=sword, but I couldn't find any grammar to help me understand the form of this phrase. Where does the "made use" come from? What does "koshi ni sashi" mean?
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: [AをBにする](http://nlp.cis.unimelb.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MUJ%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) (3) to make use of A for B; to view A as B; to handle A as if it were B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part, "katana ni shite", means to use as a katana. *

As for the other question, "koshi ni sashi" is an old way of saying, to "put in/on his belt". Koshi meaning hip, and sasu being the verb for insert/put in [belt].

*Note that this is not the same as "ni shitemo", which is a pattern meaning "even if".

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer! :)
Is there a book I can read to find these old expressions?

Comment: Sorry, not sure about books on this.  I learned that one in a class.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this as an answer but @oals explained it perfectly.
[AをBにする](http://nlp.cis.unimelb.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MUJ%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) (3) to make use of A for B; to view A as B; to handle A as if it were B.

In this case the "suru" is in the te-form, so it becomes "shite".